# Call view by dropdownlist value

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

i'm having a html.dropdownlist where ochange event is speified. i need to call a controller action method using ajax or javascript function and returns view based on the filter value

I try someting like following which is not working,why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { 
        $('#Projcbo1').change(function () {
            // fetch the newly selected value
            var selectedValue = $(Projcbo1).val();
            // send it as an AJAX request to some controller action
            $.post('@Url.Action("ProjCBOItemSelected")', { value: selectedValue }, function (result) { $("#resultContainer").html(result); });
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is the name of your action method parameter `value`?

Comment: instead of  var selectedValue = $(Projcbo1).val();   use  var selectedValue = $(this).val();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to achieve that.

```
 <script>
     $(function() { 
            $('#ddl').change(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("actionname", "controllername")',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: {Id: $(this).val() },
                    success: function (result) {

                        $('#div_to_load_the_content').html(result);

                    },
                    error: function (error) {

                    },
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Let me know if it helps.